# Volume of a parallelepiped, given three vectors

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces

I want the volume of a parallelpiped and I have the three vectors $$4e_1+2e_2-e_3$$$$e_1-3e_2-2e_3$$$$2e_1-e_2+3e_3$$ that coinciding with three of the parallelpipeds sides. HON-base

I made it into a matrice and then calculated the determinant

$$det=(4e_1*(-3e_2)*3e_3)+(2e_2*(-2e_3)*2e_1)+(-e_3*e_1*(-e_2))-(-e_3*(-3e_2)*2e_1)+(4e_1*(-2e_3)*(-e_2))+(2e_2*e_1*3e_3)=-35e_1e_2e_3$$

whitch makes the volume -35 and that is not reasonable. Where did I do wrong?
I did as it is written in this page
http://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~daddel/linear_algebra_appl/Applications/Determinant/Determinant/node11.html

Comment: As written in the link you sent, the volume is *the absolute value* of the determinant...

Comment: @DonAntonio And what is the absolute value of -35?

Comment: Er...isn't it $\,35\,$, @user1838781....?

Comment: The negative sign relates to the relative orientation of the vectors rather than the volume.

Answer (score 1):

Everything that has been said about determinants and absolute values is of course correct. But the value of your determinant is still not correct. It should be
$$\left | \begin{array}{ccc}4&2&-1\\
1&-3&-2\\2&-1&3
\end{array}\right |=
4\left |\begin{array}{cc}-3&-2\\-1 &3\end{array} \right | -
1\left |\begin{array}{cc}2&-1\\-1 &3\end{array} \right | +
2\left |\begin{array}{cc}2&-1\\-3 &-2\end{array} \right | =$$

$$=4(-9-2)-(6-1)+2(-4-3)=-44-5-14=-63$$
So the volume is $|-63|=63.$

EDIT: checking your calculation, I can see that you got the sign of the last two terms wrong (they should have a negative sign).

Comment: where did you get those numbers from?

Comment: From your vectors. I'll expand my answer ...

Answer (score 0):

According to the link you supplied, you should use the absolute value of the determinant.

```
|-35| = 35
```